# Name of trilogy about two children who find broken magic stone shards and are rescued by winged red horses

Tags: story-identification, magic

Set in almost prehistoric times in another world, two children are kidnapped.  They're seers but keep it a secret. At some point, they find missing legendary shards of a broken magic stone.  They're also rescued by winged red horses.

I read it about 6th grade, so that would have been about 1982-84. I do not think it was a new book. The children were a boy and a girl, both having the gift of foresight. The only things that I remember are the shards of a green stone - they find one in each of the books. They were kidnapped with other children and they find one shard in a tunnel on their way to where the kidnappers take them. They are given a drink called Magogweird and then red flying horses rescue them. The book jacket has a planet with two moons, a red pegasus and the two children on it. It was near Madeline l'Engle's books in the Dewey Decimal system in the Middle School library.

Comment: Welcome to the community !  Can you give us a timeframe when this might have been published or was read ? Also, were the two children boy + girl or both boys or girls ?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're after "[The Dark Green Tunnel"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/505706.The_Dark_Green_Tunnel) by Allan W. Eckert, the first part of the two part "[Mesmerian Annals](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?20225)" series.

> *The Dark Green Tunnel is a fantasy, a la C.S. Lewis, about twins (a
> boy and a girl) who find their way into a parallel world in which
> there are strange creatures, strange people, strange topography, and
> evil kings and warlocks trying to rule the entire land of Messmeria.
> The twins join the "good" forces to help overcome the evil ones. Three
> children in the Florida Everglades find an entrance to another world
> which is peopled with centaurs, gnomes, a wizard, and a wicked king,
> and where they experience both great danger and great joy.*

The cover art for the sequel featured children riding on giant red eagles;

[image]

Comment: Eckert sounds like it would be near l'Engle, (if l'Engle is filed under E not L)